# How to delete a package from HackageDB?

Tags: haskell, hackage

I have uploaded a package with incorrect name (typo) to http://hackage.haskell.org/

In the hope of not messing up HackageDB, I'm wondering if any approach to delete that package.

Thanks a lot your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only possible under very special circumstances -- contact Ross Paterson (maintainer of HackageDB) with your request, and sufficient identification to confirm that you are the author of the package.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove a package from hackage is via the administrator(s). You can email and ask for the package to be removed. But is it worth the hassle? What's so terrible if a package with a typo'ed name sits on hackage?

Comment: It would be better to clear up the clutter, rather than allow hackage to collect dust like this.